# jQuery UI tabs and tabs content in diffrent places

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, tabs

UI tabs work like this:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Need to do somethig like this:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="tabs-content">
    <div id="tabs-1">
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
    </div>
</div>
```

So tabs and tab content in different divs.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its is possible

Please check this link , and click links

http://jsfiddle.net/YJdVE/1/

code

```
$(function() {
$("#tabs ul li").click(function() {
$("#tabs-content div").hide();
$('#tabs-content div:eq('+($(this).index())+')').show();
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. It works, but it's not UI tabs. It will not work for example for AJAX load of tab contents, so need to write custom code for it.